# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity; java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, null

Im creating Triggers and Action Application for my Final Year Project,

I return a child Activity result to intermediate activity and ther add some data to that activity and send it again to main activity,

I did for both Trigger sub module and Action sub module, both like same coding....

trigger module is working perfectly, but when action module run application is force stopped

and error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {mani.droid.mechanize/mani.droid.mechanize.ActionListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Child onActivityResult**

```
public void onSave(View v)
{
    if(txtNum.length() != 0)
    {
        String strTmp = null;
        Intent resultInt = new Intent();
        strTmp = txtNum.getText().toString();
        resultInt.putExtra("Num", strTmp);
        resultInt.putExtra("SubName", strTmp);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultInt);
        finish();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter number or choose from contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Intermediate onActivityResult**

```
//getting result from other activity and sending to action list activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch(reqCode)
        {
            case 1:
                    data.putExtra("ActionName", txtAction);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main onActivityResult**

```
//Getting Trigger parameters and adding to list
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch(reqCode)
        {
            case 1:
                if (data.equals(null))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent is Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    //String actName = data.getStringExtra("ActionName");
                    String subName = data.getStringExtra("SubName");
                    Toast.makeText(context, subName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the `Intent` receiver threw an exception in its `onActivityResult()`. And I can see the `NullPointerException` right here: `data.equals(null)` is definitely wrong as it throws an exception when `data` is `null`. You mean `data == null`.

Comment: I some what managed to this problem and solved, but I don't know how it solved,
and I also tried data == null before, same error, thats why I tried data.equals(null)

Comment: Then your `NullPointerException` is elsewhere. It's directing you to a line number, so follow that. You didn't post your stack trace -- always a good idea. `data.equals(null)` is never correct in Java. It is always `false` or throws an exception.

Comment: Same question can anyone tell what is **`who=null`** ?

Answer (score 0):

just check `null != data` , as data equal null

Comment: This means the data is null?